# Fabric.js not working on IE 8

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, fabricjs

Just trying some image rotation, resizing and dragging functions of Fabric.js and it works fine on Firefox, Chrome and newer version IE. However, when I tried this on IE 8, I got error message "Unable to get property ‘length’ of undefined or null reference" from Fabric.js

From Fabric documentation, it says this could be related to "excanvas.js".So I added this like:

```
<!--[if lt IE9]><script src="excanvas.js"></script><![endif]-->
```

before calling fabric.js, but same error still occurred.

Anyone has any hints? Thanks in advance.

Comment: There may be an unsupported feature in IE8 that is supported in IE9 in Fabric.js.

Comment: Anyone knows some similar JS libraries can do the same image manipulation job(rotation, resizing and dragging)? Except JQuery UI.